# How do I know if the page is refreshed using F5 or navigated back using browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a functionality that will retain the page into its navigated state so I build it using local storage. I added remove local storage on $(document).ready to reset the view when the page is refreshed. The problem I'm encountering is when I navigated back, the local storage is removed also. How do I know if the page is refreshed using F5 or navigated back using browser back button?

Comment: In supporting browsers (i.e not so much), you can use the [PerformanceNavigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation) object to know this.

Comment: @Kaiido - The link you've provided to MDN says it's almost exclusively supported in IE, and Firefox ?

Comment: @adeneo yep but that's wrong writing an anwser

Answer (score 0):

*Note : Though MDN's article states that webkit browsers don't support it, their latest versions do on my computer.*

The [PerformanceNavigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation) Object gives you this exact information.

It's `type` property will return one of these status codes :

> - TYPE_NAVIGATE (`0`)
>     The page was accessed by following a link, a bookmark, a form submission, or a script, or by typing the URL in the address bar.
> - TYPE_RELOAD (`1`)
>     The page was accessed by clicking the Reload button or via the Location.reload() method.
> - TYPE_BACK_FORWARD (`2`)
>     The page was accessed by navigating into the history.
> - TYPE_RESERVED (`255`)
>     Any other way.

and you get it with `performance.navigation.type`.

Comment: Hello this works thanks. But when i tested it on mac. It is not supported. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: @RonellMarco which browser on mac and which osX version? It does work for me on all latest Safari, Chrome and Firefox on Sierra10.12 And since apart this API, browser behavior on page refresh/history back is not standardised, no, I know of no other ways to reliably get this info.

Comment: I'm currently using Safari v. 9.1.3 and OSX v.10.95. window.performance is undefined when I type it on the console.

Comment: @RonellMarco yes it was probably not yet implemented in Safari 9... I know it's hard, but you should consider switching to Sierra and get the safari's updates. Feels like an ipad at first, but you get used to it.